# Hyperlink numbers in excel

Tags: excel, windows-10

Long story short.
Windows 10.
Office 2013/2016
Document is exported from other system.
Cell contains hyper link with lets says "105,000" the other same is custom setting 105,000(#.###)
In this case "," represent thousands.
Client download report. Here is where regional settings and excel settings hit in.
Custom setting is converted to 105.000 but hyperlink "105,000" stays the same.(in this case "," means decimal. Should be converted to thousands)
Client claims it worked on windows 7. 
Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Eventualy have decided it should be fixed on system that gave report with hyperlink rather than trying to go create workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In general, whenever something like this happens with me in Excel I try one of these:

In Excel - `=Replace(TheHyperlink,",",".")`

With VBA - `=fnStrChangeCommas(TheHyperlink)`

```
Public Function fnStrChangeCommas(ByVal myValue As Variant) As String    
    fnStrChangeCommas = Replace(CStr(myValue), ",", ".")    
End Function
```

Comment: Technically the number in Formula bar is still with "," and in sheet.cell.value is showing number with "." when i do replace all it replaces that number also.

Comment: So you are using VBA as well, @Exmorn? Where?

Comment: I was wrong. The thing was number that working corretly have xxxx.xxx,xxx decimal hidden. So it replaces it all. Sorry for confussion no vba jut gave it as example and was wrong. It was just not showing decimal of number "," i have added some screenshot of numbers.